# Setting up Cloud Foundry on Fedora 23

Tags: fedora, cloud-foundry, fedora-23

I am trying to install Cloud Foundry on Fedora 23 and there are examples of how to install it via Debian and Redhat OS. However, the commands to carry the tasks out are usually unique to that OS.

http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/cf-cli/install-go-cli.html#linux The commands outlined for the other OSes are here.

```
Debian/Ubuntu: dpkg -i path/to/cf-cli-*.deb && apt-get install -f
 Red Hat: rpm -i path/to/cf-cli-*.rpm
```

I have extracted it via the tar -xvf command to create a single file output- no INSTALL or README file. So I am unsure how to install this tar file.

Any guidance in installing this tar file would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm no Fedora expert, but if you can't get the rpm installed then you can just download the Linux 64bit binary from https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/releases

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Dan, I installed it using the Linux 64 bit. Works just fine now.